# Angular Typescript Convert array from string to currency and percentage

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been googling for a few hours to figure out what is the EASIEST way to convert all the content in an array of string which could look like the following

```
[123.23, 234.12, 23.23] // string to currency
[1.2, 3.4, 2.2] // string to percentage
```

I readup about the Pipe in typescript like the following

```
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe , PercentPipe,   formatCurrency} from '@angular/common'
```

I looking for alternate to looping thru each array element like the following

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { myArray[i] = this.percentPipe.Transform(myArray[i]); }
```

I am looking to change the array data to currency and percentage and load the converted data to the UI. I can't use the pipe in the html mockup. I have to do it in the typescript.

I am trying to look for a better method of conversion.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are missing the point of pipe. It is to *display* the value as a (something) like currency or percentage or (whatever). *Not* to change the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrapp the iteration inside another pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'arrayConverter'})
export class YourCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(anyConverterPipe: ConverterPipe){}

  transform(values: number[]): number {
    const convertedValues = [];

    values.forEach(value => convertedValues.push(this.anyConverterPipe.transform(value)));

    return convertedValues;
  }
}
```

Then use it wherever you want.